# match complex datatype in ocaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

While matching the data bellow

```
let atable = ("Student", [("Id", ["2";"4";"7";"9"]);
                          ("Name", ["Jim";"Linnea";"Steve";"Hannah"]);
                          ("Gender",["Male";"Female";"Male";"Female"]);
                          ("Course",["Geography";"Economics";"Informatics";"Geography"])
                         ]);;
```

with this pattern

```
 let rec printTable aTable = match aTable with
      ( )->""
    | (title,[data]) -> "\n"^title^"\n\n"^printTable(data)
    | [(col,cont)::t] -> col^"   "^printTable([t])
```

I am getting an error telling me that the code is trying to match values of type 'a * 'b but the pattern is expecting to match values of type unit. What is wrong here?

Comment: I think this a case of [the XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why is your student represented by a tuple of a string and an array of tuples representing keys and values in the first place? You might be better off using a better-suited data structure instead of solving a pattern-matching problem.

Comment: I tend to agree with RichouHunter. I would rather see  : type student = {id: string; name: string; gender: string; course: string};; as  base type, and atable would be simply a list of student . But it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @PierreG.this is only an example of a table. My assignment is to make a general table datatype and to implement 3 functions on it using pattern matching and recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid confusion with the definition of `atable`, the code of `printTable` you wish to write is the following :

```
let rec printTable a = match a with
     ( )->""
   | (title,[data]) -> "\n"^title^"\n\n"^printTable(data)
   | [(col,cont)::t] -> col^"   "^printTable([t])
```

where `a` is the argument to your function.

Following [syntax of pattern matching](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html) : "The expression expr is matched sequentially to the various patterns p1, ..., pn. If one of the patterns (for example pi) is consistent with the value of expr then the corresponding computation branch (expri) is evaluated. The various patterns pi are of the same type."

In your case, you intent to match the expression `a` to 3 different types which are :

1. unit ()
2. a tuple made of something and a list of 1 element (because ; `(title,[data])` is of that type)
3. a list of a list of tuple (because `(col,cont)::t` is a list of tuples, and therefore `[(col,cont)::t]` is a list of list of tuples, even more this is a list of 1 element) .

The compiler assumes that `a` is of type unit, and then complains because the other types are not unit types.

Comment: Oh I see. Now I am confused as in the case 1 i.e. the base case I want to match the input with an empty tuple. How may I formulate that?

Comment: a tuple cannot be empty by definition ;)

Comment: as a reminder, a tuple is a cartesian product. eg: a tuple of integer (4,3) and then cannot be empty. I hope it clarifies.

Comment: ok, thank you. That sounds reasonable. How can I write a base case like in the case of lists matching with [] ?